# ferrite core code

Tags: ferrite

I have a broken ferrite core with about 3.2mm air gap (I am not sure about it).
I attached that core's picture

the code is:

> Kaschke
>
> 4 . 14  871 . 10
>
> 01/07

How can I find the characterize about this core?

Can I find the size and relative permeability of this core?

If I replace a core with the same dimensions (not exactly the same but it is near its dimension), the same number of turns and the air gap 3mm, it will work well?

[image]

Comment: you can wind a few turns of wire and measure the inductance. That will give the Al value. The ebay LCR meters work well.

Comment: Thanks for help, i have a lcr meter how can calculate Al?

Comment: I have no idea how to calculate. I use this website http://powermagnetics.co.uk/calculator . Also, this site may be of help to find Isat http://pigeonsnest.co.uk/stuff/core-saturation.html

Comment: Where’s the picture? What circuit is it used in? How many windings and turns?

Comment: thnks, but the core was broken, and Al is not exact

Comment: a power supply. 5 turns. it has a gap.

Comment: I attached the core picture, it is EE core